# Magnetic Levitation for Variable Weights

Tags: control

I'm going to build an attractive levitation module(attracting the magnet from top) that can levitate different weights(in the range of 200g to 1000g). I have built one that can nearly handle a constant weight with a -+5g tolerance using PI controller circuit by op amps.In this case, PI coefficients are fixed for this case and by changing the weight, system changes thus new coefficients are needed. How could I implement such a variable system that can handle different weights? What kind of control approaches should I use? I prefer to use analog circuit. 
[image: attractive levitation sample]

Comment: A PI controller is usually robust enough to handle a variety of different plants. Having your restriction is meaning it is just not tuned well enough.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. ,Thanks, It's robust but as mentioned just for a small range.I used the circuit of this address:http://www.bis0uhr.de/index.htm?http://www.bis0uhr.de/projekte/schwebekugel/english.php%99https://www.youtube.com/

Comment: How about a couple of potentiometers on the back so you can adjust P and I when putting in a new mass? Or does it have to be self-adjusting?  Probably one pot would be enough.

Comment: @Jack B, Thanks, I have tried it, for every new mass an adjustment works, but I wanna the circuit control it automatically not manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you could make this self adjusting within certain limits.

A solenoid (your electromagnet) exerts a force that is proportional to the current through it squared and inversely proportional to the distance squared between the solenoid and the ferrous object.

From this simple relationship, you can see if you are able to go from one amp of solenoid current to two amps, the force will increase four times at the same distance. You could therefore theoretically suspend an object with four times the mass. At 3 amps, you could suspend nine times the mass. All of this assumes that the balance of the control circuit is able to adjust to these changing masses.

And then recall that force is equal to mass times acceleration. Your device is trying to overcome the force of gravity which has an acceleration of 9.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>.

Since you have a hall effect sensor, you are able to measure the distance between the sensor and the ferrous object. This can also be used to determine the rate at which the object is falling away from or being attracted toward the sensor. The ideal rate is 0 m/s which indicates that the object is stationary because the solenoid is supplying the exact amount of force needed to overcome the gravitational force on the ferrous object.

Since the PWM circuit determines the amount of (average) current through the solenoid, you now have all the elements needed to create a closed loop control system.

I recommend that you study PID (Proportional, Integral, Derivative) control loop theory to get a handle on how to best write the formula. There you will learn about critical damping and other factors for your algorithm.

You could potentially simplify the control loop by having a starting condition where the weight is placed in contact with the solenoid and the solenoid current is set to maximum. Then start to ramp down the solenoid current until the weight attains the correct position as indicated by the hall effect sensor (remembering the force squared effect). Once in position continue to hold the position with the control loop with which you have already experimented. Not as elequent as briefly holding the weight mid air and letting go, but it is a functional approach.

It looks like a fun project - enjoy!

Comment: Thanks very much. Indeed i am familiar with PID theory. my problem is that as weight changes significantly the system with previous pid coefficients isn't suitable. then pid coefficients should be changed but how?

Comment: One of the primary adjustments to your PID loop will probably be to account for the squared term for P. With a small mass range, this could probably be ignored but now it becomes more critical to include it in the model.

Comment: thanks again. would you elaborate more on this, and how could I implement it?